# iOS-indexPath always return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I use this method get indexPath when I touch TableView

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        return nil;
    }else{
        return indexPath;
    }
}
```

And I want transfer a NSString to the second viewController,so my code like this

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSString *name =self.nameArray[indexPath.row];
    [segue.destinationViewController navigationItem].title = name;
    id theSegue = segue.destinationViewController;
    [theSegue setValue:name forKey:@"showName"];
    }
```

but indexPath always nil,and `-tableView:tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath` may be don't execute.

so how can I get the right indexPath when I touch on cell？
Thanks.

Comment: table view start with row 0. Are you sure you want to ignore first row?

Comment: Yes,the first one just a example.

Comment: You need to use tableview delegate didSelectRowAtIndextPath to get selected row informations. And don't forget set your tableview delegate.

Comment: You want to get get indexPath on didSelectRow or didDeselectRow??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // set Segue Identifier from your first viewcontroller to second viewController in stoaryboard
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstVCToSecondVCSegueIdentifier" sender:indexPath];
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstVCToSecondVCSegueIdentifier"])
    {
        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSIndexPath class]])
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
            if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondVC class]]) {
                SecondVC *aSecondVC = (SecondVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
                NSString *name =self.nameArray[indexPath.row];
                aSecondVC.title = name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worked on me,thank you very much.But I still don't understand why I could't get right indexPath.

Comment: why are you return nil in willDeselectRowAtIndexPath delegate method ?

Answer (score 0):

try this::

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER" sender:nil];

   nslog(@"tag :: %@", indexpath.row);
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
        if (indexPath != nil)
        {
     NSString *name =self.nameArray[indexPath.row];
    [segue.destinationViewController navigationItem].title = name;
    id theSegue = segue.destinationViewController;
    [theSegue setValue:name forKey:@"showName"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes,It's worked.But I want use this number in `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` So I want announce another NSInteger?

Comment: create nsinterger, and assign cell tag to nsinteger

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER" sender:nil];
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
        if (indexPath != nil)
        {
     NSString *name =self.nameArray[indexPath.row];
    [segue.destinationViewController navigationItem].title = name;
    id theSegue = segue.destinationViewController;
    [theSegue setValue:name forKey:@"showName"];
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes,the indexPath is not nil,but `indexPath`.row always 0.indexPath always 0xc000000000000016

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (nullable NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method b'coz it called before the user changes the selection. Return a new `indexPath`, or `nil`, to change the proposed selection.